# how to handle start service in landscape or portrait mode in android...?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

In My application i Have create one services for downloading data,so my requirement is when i run my application then the service call only one time. but practically is it not possible, when screen rotate from landscape mode to portrait mode then activity get Restart and services again call to avoid this problem .

Comment: **1.** You can use an independent thread to download data and manage that **2.** Search fragments and/also *retain instance state* in combination with `onConfigChange`, esp to manage the portrait, landscape mode change, if you can use fragments with activities

Comment: @user2450263 you can give me any example.or reference code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

under your activity in your manifest.

this forces the application to always be in landscape mode.

Comment: thanx for giving important time,but i have not grant permission for this  thing, it means that activity never change its Orientation.

Comment: "when screen rotate from landscape mode to portrait mode then activity get Restart and services again call to avoid this problem ." the only thing I can think off to 'hack' solve this is to force it in one orientation... this is deferentially possible as I have done it before.

Comment: your solution is  write,but still requirement is not change,

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably looking for is a [loader](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html)

Loaders automatically reconnect to the last cursor (assuming you are using one) and you do not need to re-query your backend after orientation changes.